# How to automatically create a REST API node.js / MongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, rest

I am running a node.js Server that handles REST Api calls.
The response of those calls will be either one or a list of MongoDB objects (JSON).

I already read about parameters and how to handle them. But is there any way to automatically do this?

Lets say I have a User Collection:

```
name: String,
hobby: String,
age: Number
```

Now I want to get a list of all Users that are of Age=18.

I know that I can recover parameters like this:

```
url: http://localhost:3000/user?age=18&hobby=something

var app = express();
app.get('/user', function (req,res) {

    var age=req.query.age;
    var hobby=req.query.hobby;

    mondodbUser.find(...);
}
```

But assume that the user has 10 different properties and I have 15 different Collections. Can't I just do this dynamically? So I dont have to recover every possible parameter?

I want to be able search the MongoDB the way that all given parameters are used.

I hope I could express myself good enough :D Thanks!

Comment: _assume that the user has 10 different properties and I have 15 different Collections_, can you please clarify on that?

Comment: I dont want to manually recover every single parameter from the URI and use it in the find() method for the mongoDB, but rather just call the find() Method with whatever parameters are given in the URI.

Comment: Maybe I overthink this and I could just try to retreive every parameter and just give it to the find method, even if its NULL/undefined?

Comment: So why can't you just do `User.find(req.query, cb)` since the `req.query` object will only have the properties defined in the query string, nothing more nothing less.

Comment: I can! Thanks! Thats what  I didnt know :D
Maybe I shouldve read more about the mongoDB find and req.query instead trying to find examples for the rest api thing! You can add an answer and Ill mark it as correct if you want. Not sure about this StackOverflow stuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the `req.query` returns a JS object after the query string is parsed where the object will have properties defined in the query string, e.g:

`/user?name=andrew&age=22`

`req.query` will return the object `{ name: "andrew", age: "22" }`

and thus it can be used as the `find()` method argument as long as the properties in the object match the underlying collection document schema.

You can then do:

```
app.get('/user', function (req, res) {
    User.find(req.query, function (err, users){ ... });
}
```